# SQL Query for finding the highest value of Miles

Tags: sql

Want a solution for SQL solution. 
Got a table with Days and Miles heading.
 Want to get the highest value in the table.
 At times if the vehicle is not fuctioning on a perticular day the value will be 'NULL' in Miles. 
The highest value should be calculated after 'NULL' value.
 Previous highest values are ignored and highest value has to be calculated after 'NULL' value.
 Please provide SQL query for the same.

Iam could not get solution to find the highest value after NULL occurs in table. the data is in series and after NULL occurs the highest should be calculated after NULL value appeared. It will be like 100,200,300,0,100. In this case after NULL or 0 Value 100 appeared and 100 is MAX Value

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful with appropriate DBMS tag.

Comment: `select max(miles) from the_table`?

Comment: What do we get for doing your schoolwork  ? Please post sample data, what you have tried yet and other details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `MAX()`. It is used like this:

```
SELECT MAX(<column>) FROM <table>;
SELECT MAX(<column>) FROM <table> GROUP BY <other column>;
```

If you just want to select the highest Mile value, you can do this like this:

```
SELECT MAX(Miles) FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Or

```
SELECT MAX(Miles) as MAX_MILES FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Its hard to interpret what your actually looking for. From what i can gather, this might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT MAX(Miles) as MAX_MILES FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE Days = (SELECT MAX(Days) FROM 
YOUR_TABLE WHERE Miles = NULL OR 0)
```

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you should try and post samples of your table, as well as the expected result.

However, I believe the below query might solve your problem (if I understood it corrrectly)

```
SELECT 
   MAX(MILES) 
FROM 
   TABLE
WHERE 
   DAYS > (
     SELECT MAX(DAYS) FROM
        TABLE
     WHERE MILES IS NULL);
```

Comment: just what i was thinking